# Google Sheets: Find and Replace word from WITHIN FORMLAS

Tags: google-apps-script, replace, google-sheets, formula

I need a script that Changes the `=` before each formula on a given sheet, into a `^`. This will break all the formulas on the sheet, yes, but that's what I'm going for.

An example would be a formula in cell A2 would change from `=TEXT("Hello")` to `^TEXT("Hello")`

EDIT: Yes, I know you can use CTRL-H, but I need a script

Answer (score 0):

all you need is to press **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`H`</kbd>** and do:

[image: 0]

Comment: I know that. I'm looking for a SCRIPT method to do this.